# What is the appropriate structure to setlocale for PHP gettext and avoid type definition errors

Tags: php, internationalization, gettext

THE ISSUE

I start to implement [gettext](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.gettext.php) for the [i18n](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internationalization_and_localization) in the PHP related files.
Even though there are many tutorials on the web, I have difficulties finding a clear answer **where to position the setlocale in the script ?**. Everyone seems to position it at the beginning of the script.

THE EXAMPLE

gettext works pretty fine with the following PHP functions, but I have issues with other PHP functions (see comments below):

```
$category = LC_ALL;
$locale = "fr_FR";
$domain = "messages";
$lat = 43.848977; // float with a point separator

setlocale( $category, "$locale" );
putenv( "$category=$locale" );
bindtextdomain( $domain, "./Locale" );
bind_textdomain_codeset( $domain, 'UTF-8' );

echo gettext("sample text"); // works OK

// The issue starts here
$center_lat = filter_var( $lat, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION ); 
// The float $latitude is interpreted as string due to comma in French,
// filter_var do interpret as a float anymore and $center_lat gives something like 43848977 instead of 43,848977
```

THE SOLUTION I THOUGHT

I Though that I must do something like this (almost) each time I call gettext:

```
$userLocale = setlocale( $category, 0 ); // current setting is returned
echo gettext( "sample text" );
setlocale( $category, $userLocale );

// SCRIPT RESUME

$userLocale = setlocale( $category, 0 ); // current setting is returned
echo gettext( "other text" );
setlocale( $category, $userLocale );
```

I did not find a full file example nor clear answer in the [official manual of gettext](http://www.gnu.org/software/gettext/manual/gettext.html)

I TRIED

I tried [Type Casting](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.type-juggling.php) without success:

```
$center_lat = filter_var( (float) $lat, FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT, FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION );
```

THE QUESTION

Is my solution the way to go to avoid unexpected errors (whether it is Type Casting or any other) ?

Answer (score 2):

filter_var() is usually used to check your web form input, where the input values are given in string I think. In what situation will it need to check float by filter_var()?

Anyway, to check locale formatted number, you could use php_intl extension to convert the French number string to regular one, then filter_var() should work.

```
if (!class_exists('NumberFormatter')) {
    exit ('You need to install php_intl extension.');
}

$category = LC_ALL;
$locale = "fr_FR";
$domain = "messages";
$lat = '43,848977';

setlocale( $category, "$locale" );
putenv( "$category=$locale" );
bindtextdomain( $domain, "./Locale" );
bind_textdomain_codeset( $domain, 'UTF-8' );

$localeFormatter = new \NumberFormatter($locale, \NumberFormatter::DECIMAL); 
$center_lat = filter_var(
    $localeFormatter->parse($lat),
    FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_FLOAT,
    FILTER_FLAG_ALLOW_FRACTION
);
echo $center_lat . PHP_EOL;
```

Comment: This solution is interesting but is not global. It just applies to float (what about other types I may run into) and it does not tell me if THE SOLUTION I THOUGHT is the appropriate way

Comment: If your input parameters are not in French, but your output are in French, yes, you need to switch locale. If both are in French, I will have no reason to switch locale every time. I would rather write codes to assure that both input and output would be in French.